# If...Then Statement For runners in a race and finishing place

Tags: if-statement, visual-studio-2012, conditional-statements

I'm working on an assignment in Visual Studio Express 2012, and the challenge asks me to create an app that allows a user to enter three runners' names and finishing times.  I'm working on the flowchart for the If...Then...Else portion for the first, second and third place winners.  Can anyone help me or steer me in the right direction for creating the conditional statement portion?

Here's what I have:

```
If intRunner1 < intRunner2 And intRunner1 < intRunner3 Then
    lblDisplay.Text = "First Place"
End If
If intRunner2 < intRunner1 And intRunner2 < intRunner3 Then
    lblDisplay.Text = "First Place"
End If
If intRunner3 < intRunner1 And intRunner3 < intRunner2 Then
   lblDisplay.Text = "First Place"
```

I also have this:

```
If intFinish1 < intFinish2 Then
    If intFinish1 < intFinish3 Then
        lblFirstPlace.Text = "Runner 1 finished in first place."
    Else
        lblSecondPlace.Text = "Runner 1 finished in second place."
Else
    If intFinish1 < intFinish3 Then
        lblFirstPlace.Text = "Runner 1 finished in second place."
    Else
        lblThirdPlace.Text = "Runner 1 finished in thirdplace"
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If all data is input at the same time :

You should make 2d array of size equal to the number of runners. Insert the name of the runner in the first dimension, and runner time in the second. Then sort this array on the 2nd dimension to get winners. As the scope is very small and just for demonstration, you can just use a if then else condition to check for the sorting.

1. If you input the runner one at a time

Just insert the runners in the 2d array in the correct order and out put the array after all data has been inserted to get list of winners.

For example pseudocode for second method :

```
create 2d array A
repeat for each runner
  input runner name
  input runner time
     if A has runners
      check runner against each runner in A
            insert runner at the correct position
     else
       insert runner in A
end repeat
```

1. If you are only using variables and not arrays : Let us assume u have runners A B & C
   These are the possible scenarios : ABC, ACB, BAC, BCA, CAB, CBA
   You have to check for each of them.

```
    Take A
       if A beats B (then he is definately second or first)
         if A beats C (then he is definately first)
           A is first
           if B beats C
              B is second, C is third
           else 
              C is second, B is third
         else
           A is second
           if B beats C
              B is first, C is third
           else 
              C is first, B is third
       else ... if A beat C.... and so on
```

Project this to check for every possible scenario.

Comment: i would not give you the code on how to do it as this looks like homework. But the pseudocode whould get you started.

Comment: :( I haven't learned arrays yet. I'm expected to use an If...Then, If...Then...Else, or even a Select Case statement.  The pseudocode would be great help, even a portion of the code would be great.

Comment: check out the last part. Write code until you have covered all possible winning scenarios. and that's it.